# Draw rectangles in pinescript tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I am working on a simple indicator in pinescript tradingview to draw a rectangle on a chart but getting confused with error messages.

Can any one point me to something similar (anything welcome) so I can adapt the code?

update ...

removed errors by changing version no. but nothing happens on the chart
also working through debug info to help myself

Update ...

Found, all ok

```
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html
```

Comment: Please show us your error messages and what you have done so far.